# Fitting a linear model using lm and a variable as factor

Tags: r, linear-model

I am new to R and I'm confused by

```
lin_mod <- lm(temp~as.factor(activ), data=beav2)
```

specifically `as.factor(activ)`. Why do we need the `as.factor`?

The whole question is

> Fit a linear model using `lm` and the variable `activ` as factor, viz. `lin_mod <- lm(temp~as.factor(activ), data=beav2)`. Overlay the means on your plot with `lines(fitted(lin_mod))` replacing `lin_mod` with your `lm` result.

And why should I replace `lin_mod`? Aren't my results already in it?

Comment: This question a) appears to be self-study (see our homework policy on the help page), and b) may be more about programming than statistics per se.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have access to your data. However, in general, people code categorical variables as 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. If you don't specifically tell your software to treat a categorical independent variable as categorical, it will treat it as continuous.

If the variable in question is binary and is coded as 0 vs 1, then no big deal.

If it's not binary, then it's a big deal. Imagine the variable in question were age groups, for example.

Comment: In addition, if the variable is a character variable (text) and not numeric R will automatically treat it as a factor variable so you do not need as.factor().

Comment: @Glen didn't know that about R. Thanks!